# How to store multiple Select option on diferent variables using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, select, dropdown

I would like to know how can I store different options selected on a select input and put them on different variables.

example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="operacoes">Operações Possíveis</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow" data-width="100%" title="Clique aqui para selecionar um nível .." id="operacoes" name="operacoes[]" multiple>
                <option value="1">Adiciona</option>
                <option value="1">Remove</option>
                <option value="1">Altera</option>
                <option value="1">Pesquisa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and get the result in different variables :

```
var a = $('#operacoes').val(1);
var b = $('#operacoes').val(1);
var c = $('#operacoes').val(1);
var d = $('#operacoes').val(1);
```

and if not selected .val(0);

Comment: `.val(1)` is for setting the value, not reading the value.

Comment: Why do you have the same value for different options?

Comment: It's because I'm making a level table that lets the administrator create levels, and each level the administrator can provide what action each level can do..

Comment: That doesn't explain why they're all `value="1"`. How do you know which action they chose if they all have the same value?

Comment: Yes, I know that .val(value) sets a number, I was just exemplifying a result.

Comment: I know because my table columns just receive 0/1 to know if the action is performed by that level or not

Comment: That's now how `<select>` works. You use the value to know *which* options were chosen. If you want to know which level it is, you should put that somewhere else, like a `data-level` attribute of the `<select>`

Comment: And that's why i wanted to separate the values into different values to send it using an Ajax function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('selector').val() will return selected values in array.
Without selecting any values below code will print undefined and that is obvious. Hope below answer will help to solve your problem.

**JavaScript:**

```
function getSelectedValue() {
  const values = $('#operacoes').val();

  $('#selectedValues').html(values[0] + ', ' + values[1]);
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="operacoes">Operações Possíveis</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select class="selectpicker show-tick show-menu-arrow" data-width="100%" title="Clique aqui para selecionar um nível .." id="operacoes" name="operacoes" multiple>
                <option value="Adiciona">Adiciona</option>
                <option value="Remove">Remove</option>
                <option value="Altera">Altera</option>
                <option value="Pesquisa">Pesquisa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="getSelectedValue()" value="Print Selected Value" />
<div id="selectedValues"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `values.join(',')` to show all of them?

Comment: I tried but I'm getting a [object HTMLOptionElement] result instead of the result "1" that I wanted!

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, I could have used `join`. But I was just giving @Muhamad Yuraz an idea to achieve what he was looking for.